# Why webpage with two modal not work, the first i click make frizze

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

In my page, I have two modals, when open the first modal made a frieze.
I have one button for other modal

Why don't work is some limitation from bootstrap?

Comment: post your code, so that we can solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each modal should be given a **different id** and **each link** should be targeted to a different modal id. So it should be something like that:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
<a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
```

In this way, It will work. If you click the first link, it should pop-up the first modal and if you click the second - the second modal is popped up.

Comment: It is Working or not Working?

Comment: Unfortunately don't woriks